# Android BottomNavigationView like in the Google I/O 2017 APP

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview

How did Google implemented BottomNavigationView without shift mode in their Google I/O 2017 app?
(https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.samples.apps.iosched&hl=en)

Did they changed the BottomNavigationView?
Can not find how they did it.